# Apache Tomcat 7 -Parameters lost

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

We are facing a weird issue where a similar configuration is yielding unexpected results for consecutive requests on Tomcat 7.0.54.

We have enabled the request dumper filter on Tomcat 7 and it shows that consecutive requests are missing the parameters.

Due to this our application is throwing a backend error and giving a bad user experience of not letting the user complete a transaction.

Did anyone face a similar issue on Tomcat 7 ?I can share more configuration files as required to help give more details on the issue.

Helpful pointers are greatly appreciated.

LOG link:

[Log file](http://www.filedropper.com/requestdumper)

TCP dump -8009

[TCP dump](http://www.filedropper.com/tcpdump)

Saludos

Kartheek

Comment: You haven't attached anything.  (It sounds like the information you were trying to attach shouldn't be too large, so could you just include it in your question?)

Comment: Are you sure about without pattern? Usually there is a pattern that's not obvious. Anyway, how is the request made? What is the front end stack look like? How are you setting the parameters? How often does this happen, how many filters do you have and what order they're invoked?

Comment: @prabugp: We are not aware of any specific pattern.The transaction is going through Browser [HTTP | Port 80] >> Web Server [HTTP | Port 80] >> Mod JK [AJP 13 | Port 8009] >> Tomcat [AJP 13 | Port 8009].The parameters are submitted through a form POST.We roughly see this issue once in 5 times.The log which we attached is from the tomcat's request dumper filter which is supposedly the first filter before any of the application level filters are invoked which means that our application is not even receiving them.Hope this gives you a better idea.

Comment: Can you do a sniffing of your raw request at the web server as well as at the Mod JK level? Could any of these components do a redirect/forward/cache the request/do some intelligent stuff with the request or could the page itself do a double submit upon some JS code invocation? and any way your front end stack could do something on a trigger/event?

Comment: Added the tcp dump for port 8009 which is the last layer before the request dumper log and the parameters are found in both the cases.(please ignore the file name in the logs)

Comment: No chance of double submit as we are clearly seeing a one-one correspondence in the logs.

Comment: We upgraded the Linux kernel version and issue seems to be gone for now.